# How to get streaming data from darwin server

Tags: java, java-me

I am able to request darwin server and also getting response from darwin server but i am not getting, How to get that requested video file streaming data on my client side?
i am using socket `DatagramConnection socket= (DatagramConnection)Connector.open("datagram://:8080");` but i am getting following error

```
connection class not found
  org.microemu.microedition.io.ConnectorImpl.openSecure(null:-1)
    Exception in thread "main" javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException
at org.microemu.microedition.io.ConnectorImpl.openSecure(Unknown Source)
at org.microemu.microedition.io.ConnectorImpl.access$200(Unknown Source)
at me2.h.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.microemu.microedition.io.ConnectorImpl.open(Unknown Source)
at org.microemu.microedition.io.ConnectorAdapter.open(Unknown Source)
at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(Unknown Source)
at RTPSourceStream.<init>(RTPSourceStream.java:46)
at RTSPrequest.main(RTSPrequest.java:48)
```

How to get streaming data of requested URL? I am not getting link related to this
can anyone suggest me link for it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  DataInputStream class to get the relevant streaming data.

Just like downloading of an Image with Stream Data Connection.